# What is the easiest way for navigating through a DOMString?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a `DOMString` which is of kind

```
"<!DOCTYPE html><html><div id="d1"><p>foo</p></div></html>"
```

and I want to store the paragraph content in a variable (say, `pContent`), such that

```
pContent == "foo"
```

What do you suggest me? I can use only javascript-code (and libraries entirely written in `.js` if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you mentioned the use of libraries, you can pass the contents of your string to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and extract the tree. For example:

```
var myString = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><div id="d1"><p>foo</p></div></html>',
    $myString = $(myString),
    para = $myString.find('p').text();
```

Your variable `para` now contains the string `foo`.

Comment: I think you meant `$myString = $( myString )`, right? btw, I wish your suggestion could work, but seems like it's not. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed mean `$(myString)`.

Comment: Yet the rest of the piece is right? Can you test it again? I can't get it working...

Comment: The return value from $(myString) is div#d1, your find query should simply be .find('p'). Like this `$('<!DOCTYPE html><html><div id="d1"><p>foo</p></div></html>').find('p').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JS:

```
var str = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><div id="d1"><p>foo</p></div></html>';

var htmlWrapper = document.createElement('html');
htmlWrapper.innerHTML = str;
var pNodes = htmlWrapper.getElementsByTagName('p');

pContent = pNodes[0].innerText || pNodes[0].textContent;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N47z/)

Although, JQuery would be a better solution but adds a lot of functionality you may not need.